# searching within string python iterables vs list iterables

Tags: python

Could someone explain why a search as  follows

2,2,2,2 in range(20)

yields a result as (2, 2, 2, True)

and 5,4,3,19 in range(20)

yields a result as (5, 4, 3, True)

A search like "tab" in "batman" gives False whereas "bat" in "batman" is true. Likewise why is the order not preserved in the above searches. Also I'd like an explanation of the results it gives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
2,2,2,2 in range(20)
```

Python sees it this way:

```
2,2,2,(2 in range(20))
```

You expected it to be treated this way:

```
(2,2,2,2) in range(20)
```

But since Python is not vector-oriented, it doesn't work like that.  NumPy is more appropriate if you prefer to program in terms of vectors, but for basic Python comparisons it doesn't work the way you thought.

As for this:

```
"tab" in "batman"
```

Of course it returns false, because the string `"tab"` is not in the string `"batman"`.  It's a string search, not a search for characters (i.e. it does not look for anagrams).

Comment: And of course `[c in "Batman" for c in "tab"]` results in `[True, True, False]`.

Answer (score 1):

`2,2,2,2 in range(20)` 
constructs a tuple with four elements, the first three being 2, and the last is the Boolean expression `2 in range(20)` which evaluates to `True`.

In python, the comma creates a tuple. *which is a little bit confusing.*

So, `2,` would create a new single valued tuple
While, `(2)` would return an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is a boolean expression. So when you enter `2,2,2,2 in range(20)` what you are doing in creating a tuple with three 2's and the result of the Boolean expressin `2 in range(20)`, which is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`in` calls the `__contains__` method of the object, so

```
 2,2,2,2 in range(20)
```

means

```
 2,2,2,(range(20).__contains__(2))
```

and

```
 5,4,3,19 in range(20)
```

means

```
 5,4,3,(range(20).__contains__(19))
```

so the object returned by `range`<sup>*</sup> decides how `in` behaves.

strings have a different behaviour for `__contains__`. It works as a substring search.

`2,2,2,2 in range(20)` is an unusual expression. It's possible you mean something like

```
all(x in range(20) for x in (2,2,2,2))
```

`*` In Python2 `range` returns a `list` and in Python3 it returns a `range` object